# scala: generic function from type T to Type T while performing transformations of the input

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, typeclass

I have the following *very* contrived example:

```
def f[T](t: T): T = {
  t match {
    case a : Int => a * 2
    case _ => t
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: T
           case a : Int => a * 2
                             ^
```

**My questions are:**

1. Why does the compiler not reconcile the `Int` as `T`?
2. except for converting to `(a * 2).asInstanceOf[T]` is there any other strategy to manipulate something polymorphically returning an instance of the same type when nothing special is known about `T`? (save for type classes?)

---

Notice please the following type class implementation, is *even* less elegant:

```
trait Manipulator[A] {
  def manip(a: A): A
}

implicit object IntManip extends Manipulator[Int] {
  override def manip(a: Int): Int = a * 2
}

implicit object WhateverManip extends Manipulator[Any] {
  override def manip(a: Any): Any = a
}
def g[T](t: T)(implicit manipulator: Manipulator[T]) = {
  manipulator.manip(t)
}

g(2)

g(2.3.asInstanceOf[Any])(WhateverManip)
```

I would have been able to do away with the `asInstanceOf[Any]` had `Manipulator` been contravariant, but...:

```
trait Manipulator[-A] {
  def manip(a: A): A
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:13: error: contravariant type A occurs in covariant position in type (a: A)A of method manip
         def manip(a: A): A
```

Comment: thanks to the gitter scala channel we have a reason as to why  http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/07/06/singleton_instance_trick_unsafe.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With literal types enabled you can call `f[3](3)`. Without literal types, in standard, current, no-options Scala you can still do `val a = new Integer(3); f[a.type](a)`. If you fix type parameter `T` to be `3`, this means the return type also has to be `3`. And the type `3` is only inhabited by the value `3`, which means it would be wrong to return `3 * 2`. But `3` is also an instance of `Int`, so `case a: Int` will work for it. Only that doesn't prove that `T =:= Int`.
2. Without type classes you can do close to nothing with `t` if you don't use type casing and type casting. That is actually the beauty of [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity).

You can fix your typeclass by introducing priority if you want to have a default fall-back instance.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Manipulator[A] {
  def manip(a: A): A
}

object Manipulator extends LowerPriority {
  implicit object IntManip extends Manipulator[Int] {
    override def manip(a: Int): Int = a * 2
  }
}

trait LowerPriority {
  implicit def WhateverManip[T] = new Manipulator[T] {
    override def manip(a: T): T = a
  }
}


def g[T](t: T)(implicit manipulator: Manipulator[T]) = {
  manipulator.manip(t)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> g(2)
res0: Int = 4

scala> g(2.3)
res1: Double = 2.3
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I have seen some `LowerPriority...` implicit definitions before, but never actually given it much thought. Could you please elaborate on point #1 (with and without literal types enabled)?